# Does meosis takes place in cell cycle?

Tags: cell-cycle

Cell cycle is as follows- g1,s,g2,m( mitosis). Does this m stands for mitosis only or does this "m" stands for meosis also

Comment: Do you Know what the difference between mitosis and meiosis is?

Comment: The headline of your question seems to be incomplete. Is there a word missing?

Comment: Yes i know that

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of convention really.

When people discuss the cell cycle, they usually refer to diploid cells (for diploid animals). So in your context, **M** stands for mitotic phase and does not directly apply to meiosis.

In meiosis, you could say that the cell also undergo a M-phase (actually two in a row, see footnote) but then the cell cycle becomes irrelevant as you get 4 haploid cells (gametes) that cannot duplicate by themselves anymore, effectively breaking the cycle.

### Footnote

The M-phase in the cell cycle is a simplification of the process of cell division as this phase can be further sub-divided into a Prophase, Metaphase, Anaphase, Telophase (PMAT for the purists) followed by cytokinesis. In meiosis, you have a slightly different PMAT process during meiosis I (i.e. 1 cell -> 2 cells) followed by another PMAT (2 cells -> 4 cells). You can find additional information [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/cellular-molecular-biology/meiosis/a/phases-of-meiosis).